# Interface para construir relações entre tabelas

Tags: php, modelagem

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação onde basicamente o utilizador irá fazer relação entre tabelas MySQL. Por exemplo:

- tabela A (Produtos)
- tabela B (Fotos)
- tabela C (Histórico de preços).

Basicamente na aplicação teria que ter o seguinte:

- O utilizador escolhe as tabelas envolvidas;
- O utilizador diz que ao adicionar uma nova foto, o ID do produto deve ser incluído;
- O utilizador diz que quando o preço for alterado, deve incluir o preço na tabela de históricos utilizando o ID do produto.

Bom, é só uma introdução para o problema.
O problema é evitar programação e utilizar ao máximo a interface, porém isso é uma regra entre várias possíveis.

A questão é, estou a ir por um caminho errado, sem saída?
Existe alguma aplicação que faça isso (não faz tudo mas já faz muito e com certeza há) e estou a reinventar a roda? 
Mesmo que não seja PHP+MySQL, o que importa é o conceito.

Comment: vc quer criar algo como o phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Não, conheço e utilizo o phpMyAdmin. O que eu quero é desenvolver algo para popular as tabelas para o utilizador comum. Imagina que o cliente quer uma nova area no site apenas para apresentar o produto. O programador teria que criar no backoffice a gestão dos produtos, no php dizer que quando alterar o preço incluir uma nova linha na tabela de historico de produtos, preparar upload de imagens para a galeria...

Comment: Então você quer um "Populador" de dados?

Comment: O "populador" de dados seria gerado conforme as configurações e relações entre tabelas.

Comment: Felipe, sempre que possível, **[edit]e** a pergunta para acrescentar informações e esclarecimentos. Depois, avise outros usuários usando `@NomeDoUsuario` aqui nos comentários. Só dá pra notificar um usuário a cada comentário, e o autor da pergunta/resposta é sempre notificado.

Answer (score 1):

Para `php + MySQL` existe o [WorkBench](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-gui.html)

Ele é uma aplicação para modelagem do banco de dados de forma visual/designer, muito útil e que permiti você ver/construir na forma de diagrama e schemas as relações e views do seu banco e lhe permitir já criar no momento a base de dados ou até mesmo retornar código php para sua utilização, veja [WorkBench generate php code](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-generating-php.html)

No caso de *Populador* de dados, costumo usar este [carinha] aqui para gerar minhas mocks de dados.
Muito bom, simples, considerei auto-intuitivo e além de tudo free...

Comment: Então, o que pretendo é evitar que o programador faça programação e apenas configuração. Já existe um BO para o site, porém se quiser criar uma nova área no site e gerir o conteúdo no site, teria que programar o BO para editar as informações, com a aplicação pretendo apenas inserir relações entre tabelas e a tela que irá gerir o conteúdo seria "montada" automaticamente.

Comment: O que você quer fazer se chama `Scaffold`... No `ZEND`,  `CodeIgniter`, `ASP.NET MVC`, `CakePHP`, já trabalham com isso, em cima da sua classe(`MVC`) ou do banco inteiro (`CakePHP` por exemplo) eles geram sua tela e controladores

Comment: Exato, isso que pretendo fazer... mas é um caminho complicado e podem existir N regras, relação quando se edita um campo, relação quando se insere um novo registo, etc...

Comment: Você está querendo criar algo como um Genexus da vida, mas vão ser necessário muitos anos de estudo para amadurecer algo assim, mas também existem coisas que você vai precisar deixar programar, pois cada sistema tem um comportamento unico em certas situações

Comment: Já possuímos uma plataforma própria aqui na empresa, porém podemos melhora-la para que o programador não perca tempo a construir áreas no BO realizando tarefas que são comuns a cada novo projeto, mas a minha preocupação é fazer algo que seja muito pouco reaproveitado.